# Hide/Show Fields when Picklist value is selected in Case and have separate views for each type of Case

Tags: visualforce, picklist, record-type, case-object, custom-view

I'm fairly new to Salesforce and Apex. From the research I have done, I am under the impression that the solution I need is not an easily achievable one and I will have to create a VF page.

I would like to (upon creating a new case) select a case type from a picklist. Once the type has been selected, have the appropriate fields appear for that type (and only those fields). Each type of case will have a set of different fields. Also, once the case is saved, I would like to have a separate view for each type.

Is this achievable? Where do I begin with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually fairly simple: **record types**.

Even though this actually depends on your business model and may not be suitable for yours depending on the specifications, I recommend you read about it to double check if the application of them serve your use case.

**Instead of having a picklist as such, which is a field, you would create a record type, which is a different type of metadata**. Then whenever the user is going to create a record he will be asked for the record type, even before having access to the layout to fill the fields in.

**The main advantage of record types is that you can give each of them a different layout**, so you can hide/display fields at will. This is later complemented with Salesforce visibility rules (profiles, etc.).

Even though I would generally recommend you to read some trailheads (which I still do), I found [this article](https://www.adminhero.com/hands-on-with-page-layouts-and-record-types/) which is more specific in order to understand record types and page layouts. In [this url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet/recordtypes_cheatsheet.htm) there are some tips and tricks for using record types

Lastly, remember to **take into account that this solution I'm proposing is condition by your business model and the use case**, which is not shared in your question. If at any point you see it does not fit your need, you might have to implement a more complicated solution.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for! Thank you for saving me from headache